# Showing image on mouseout

Tags: jquery

I have this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mLa313px/27/

I have an image and some links. When i hover on an image,there some css3 scaling that take place. When i click on the image,i intend to hide the image i clicked and show the links instead,and when on mouseout of the now visible links,i want to display the image i clicked.

This is the code so far

```
$(".linkso").addClass('hide');
$(".flood").hover(function() {
        $(".flood").addClass('transition');
    }, function() {
        $(".flood").removeClass('transition');
        $(".linkso").addClass('hide');
    });

$(".flood").click(function() {     
    if ($(".linkso").hasClass("hide")) {
     $(".linkso").removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```

How can i improve my code to do that?.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".linkso").addClass('hide');
$(".flood").hover(function() {
        $(".flood").addClass('transition');
    }, function() {
        $(".flood").removeClass('transition');
    });

$(".flood").click(function() {     
    if ($(".linkso").hasClass("hide")) {
     $(".linkso").removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```

[here is the modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLa313px/28/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the image on click, then you should use css `visibility` property.

css:

```
.visibilityHide{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mLa313px/29/